# Black Scholes Proof Questions

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, gaussian-integral

Let Z be a standard normal random variable. Recall that we can express a
geometric Brownian motion as
$ S(t) = S_0e^{σ\sqrt{t}Z+(r−σ^2/2)t}, t > 0.$

Show that:

$ e^{−rt}E[S(t) · Z · 1_{{S(t)>k}}] = S_0(Φ'(d1) + σ\sqrt{t}Φ(d1)).$

$ e{−rt}E[S(t) · 1_{S(t)>k}] = S_0Φ(d1).$

We're asked to prove both equations. I'm having a hard time getting started even. Thanks for any potential help.

Comment: Can you at least write down what the left and right sides are completely? That should get you started. Pull stuff out of the $E$ that you can should help too

Comment: Do you know if the stuff inside the expected value should end up being independent? I'm assuming not because then the E(Z) would make the left hand side 0. I'm just having trouble combining the S(t) and Z. I think the second part is implied after finishing the first part, so I'm less worried about that one.

Comment: Obviously they won't be independent. You can pull out some stuff not related to $Z$ and use the definition of expectation.

Comment: Remember that an expectation is an integral. $E[f(S)]=\int_0^{\infty}f(S)p(S)dS$

Comment: Check here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411780/easy-proof-of-black-scholes-option-pricing-formula